# Checking if the first string is smaller or equal than the corresponding letter in the second string

Tags: java, string, loops, integer

I am trying to take two strings and compare their lengths. If they are not equal in length the program will simply print "Bye", however if they are equal I would like to check that every letter in the first string is smaller or equal than the corresponding letter in the second string. If this holds, it should print TRUE else it should print FALSE.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
public class hw3_task2 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.printf("Enter the first string: ");
    String a = in.nextLine();
   System.out.printf("Enter the second string: ");
    String b = in.nextLine();

  char [] _a = a.toCharArray();
  char [] _b = b.toCharArray();

  if (a.length() == b.length());

boolean flag = true;
for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
      System.out.printf("TRUE\n");
      System.out.printf("Bye\n");

  if( _a[i] != _b[i]){
    flag = false;
    System.out.printf("Bye\n");
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: By comparing if a letters is smaller... what do you mean?

Comment: you will need to convert your Strings to arrays of chars, so consider https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()

Comment: outide of that put them both into char arrays and compare with a for loop...

Comment: I believe it means 'a' would be smaller than 'b', if they were given values like a = 1 and b = 2.

Comment: `char a = 'a'; char b = 'b';  if (a < b)`  ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you simply use the [String compareTo()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_compareto.htm) function?  It seems to do exactly what you need:

```
String a = "cats";
String b = "cuts";
String result = "";
if(a.length() != b.length()){
    result = "BYE";
}
else if (a.compareTo(b) <= 0){
    result = "TRUE";
}
else{
    result = "FALSE";
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Wow I completely overlooked this answer, I'm sorry. This is actually exactly what I needed, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a for loop using the `length` method.

You can get the letter at a given position using [CharSequence#charAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#charAt-int-).

`String` implements `CharSequence` so you can do `a.charAt(i);`

Comment: I'm a little confused! How can I compare each individual letter with the corresponding second string? If I hard-coded it then it would be limited to however many letters I do it for, right?

Comment: At this point of the code, they're the same length, so you can compare a.charAt(i) with b.charAt(i) without problem.

Comment: You're right, avoid hard coding things. That's usually a very bad practice. There are almost always ways to make your code flexible, for instance here by using length().

Comment: Yes sir, but it could be any number of letters, right? Am I overthinking this? Like if I had to compare the 50th letter of each string to one another?

Comment: I don't understand your concern. If you use a loop, it takes care of going through the whole length, be it 2 or 500 characters long.

Comment: Oh! I see! I think I'm just a little confused on -how- to do it, but I understand the process a little better now.

Comment: I suggest you write a `for` loop starting from 0 and going through the whole length. Retrieve the character at the given position using the method I gave you above. Inside the loop, use System.out.println(myChar). If you can do that, you're 90% done. (the println being just for you to see what your program does)

Comment: If you struggle with the for loop, I suggest you create a new class with a `main` that you can compile and run, and start playing with for loops there. This way your code will be much easier to understand and you don't risk to mess with your assignment code.

Comment: `else if (a.length() == b.length());

    for(int i = 0; i < a.charAt(i); i++){
    System.out.println(i);
    }
       System.out.printf("Bye\n");`

Comment: Bleh, formatting in comments didn't work. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Not quite. The 2nd part of a for loop is a boolean expression (true/false) that keeps the loop going. You want to keep going until you've reached the end of the String (hint: length).

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= b.length(); i++){` Something like this? Now how can I print whether or not the value is true or false?

Comment: System.out.println(i <= b.length()) or if you prefer, boolean test = i <= b.length(); or if you prefer with parenthesis, boolean test = (i <= b.length()); then System.out.println(test);

Comment: I just keep getting outputs like `true true true true bye true bye`, how can I just get a single output of true/false?

Comment: When do you want to print false? You're printing the loop condition inside the loop, so it's always true :-) Maybe do you wanted to add `System.out.println("i = " + i + ", char A = " + a.charAt(i) + ", char B = " + b.charAt(i));`

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop the individual chars in your strings

```
for (int x = 0; x < a.length(); x++) {

    if (a.charAt (x) > b.charAt (x)) {
        System.out.println ("First String is BIGGER");

        // maybe break now ?
    }
}
```

Comment: your going to have a "First String is BIGGER" every time a character in `a` is bigger.. Not that its bad, i just didint read the question that way and wasint sure if you saw 07

Comment: @R.Hull Hence why I wrote // maybe break now

Answer (score -1):

I like the `charAtSequence()` suggested by pyb, my own first instinct however would be char array. I think they both will work the same though. I didint want to write the whole code for you, but I hope this helps...

```
  char [] _a = a.toCharArray();  // note 1
   //do the same for the b string here...

  else if (a.length() == b.length());

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){  // note 2
      //compare each character here..
    }
       System.out.printf("Bye");
  }
```

Here are some good resources on `toCharArray()` if you need more help or understanding

[java documentation on `tocharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29)

[beginner's guide to `toCharArray()`](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-tochararray-method-example/)

note 1:  this line sets aside a char[] variable ( an array of characters) : `char[]_a`

the second par `= a.toCharArray`  uses a method of the String class that will instantiate a char array of the length of string `a`
then take every letter of the String `a` and place them into the char[] array..

so....

```
  String a  = cat
  char[] _a = a.toCharArray();
```

results in an array characters

[c]

[a]

[t]

now we preform the same manipulation with string `b`....

```
   String b  = cat
  char[] _b = b.toCharArray();
```

this (since the strings are equivalent) will result in equivalent arrays.. however you must test this to be sure.

to test the equivalency of these arrays we must test each index against the corresponding index... we will do so with a `for` loop

This for loop, as shown above [note 2] is set to run through the same number of rotations as the array is long. (I'm not sure how to phrase this right now I'm not using my words well tonight, so if you can phrase that better please do...) then we will compare each index to the cooresponding one here...

```
    boolean flag = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){  
    // ( or > or < or >= or <= ) however it is you wish to compare these
      if( _a[i] != _b[i]){
        flag = false;
      }
    }
```

And then if flag == true, print out your corresponding message else.. print other message...

for this answer..

```
    if( _a[i] != _b[i]){
       flag = false;
       System.out.printf("Bye\n");
    }
```

Take your System.out.print, and move it outside your loop..

everytime your loop passes through it prints bye...

try a statment that prints Flag and bye...

Comment: Could you please explain how the first line works? I'm really unfamiliar with the syntax. (i'd upvote you if i could but it wont let me rate comments.)

Comment: `  char [] _a = a.toCharArray();`  ?

Comment: Yes, I'm not quite sure how it works, am I supposed to fill in the variable for []?  Do I use the same syntax for the second string?

Comment: I think so! So we are using the boolean to decide whether or not it prints TRUE or FALSE, how can it flag it as FALSE when a > b?

Comment: instead of `!= ` use `_a[i] > _b[i]`

Comment: this will `Flag` as `false` if ANY letter in `a` is greater than its partner in `b` even if a letter in `b` is greater than its partner in `a`

Comment: I'll edit the original post using this method, could you tell me why when I enter the strings "cut" and "cat" I get an output like `TRUE
Bye
TRUE
Bye
Bye
TRUE
Bye`? I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: To expand a little bit, it should only print False and Bye in two different lines.

Comment: Yes ^, and you have two extra print lines from the previous code in side he loop you may want to get rid of..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How can I move it outside of the loop if I want the false flag to remain inside the loop?